Where can I find The Holy Geeta by Swami Chinmayananda with *Good Quality Pages*?
My friend narrated a few verses of The Holy Geeta by Swami Chinmayananda and I absolutely loved it, but upon reading it myself I realised that it has terrible page quality. On amazon even the hardcover version thas the same paper quality, where can I find the same book but in good paper quality? My eyes hurt when I read those kind of pages where you can see the other page text beneath. Thank You!

Free kindle edition is available on amazon

@estimator Thanks, I don’t have a kindle though, and I prefer to read a physical book :)

No need for kindle device. Kindle app for mobile is sufficient and it is free. But, of course, I understand you are looking for a physical book.
